# cqrs: Sharing Command and Event semantics between services

Tags: jakarta-ee, cqrs

I don't quite figure out how to share command and event classes between services.

1. Sharing jars? Here, there's a big problem because create dependencies between services!
2. I've been reading about Avro and schema.org, but I don't quite figure out how to use them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't quite figure out how to share command and event classes between services.

You don't share command and event classes between services.  You share command and event *schema* between services.

[Udi Dahan, 2014](https://vimeo.com/113515335)

> Services share contract and schema, not class or type.... Other than an agreement on communications, nothing else.

Furthermore, you invest design capital in the schema, so that you can evolve your messages in a forward/backward compatible way.  Greg Young's book on [Versioning in an Event Sourced System](https://leanpub.com/esversioning) is my go to reference on that, but in truth many of the messaging standards have references discussing the same ideas.

The basic idea is this; you take some information you want to communicate, and you use your schema to convert that information to bytes, which you send to me.  I use my schema to convert the bytes back into information.  If my schema and yours are compatible, then I will understand your message.

The motivation for this is that you are trying to support independent deployments of the services.  If you need to *extend* your message schema, you should be able to redeploy the blue service, and then later the red service (or vice versa) without breaking the system.  The red and blue schema don't need to by synchronized, just compatible.

Avro, Thrift, Protocol Buffers are all systems for describing information in bytes.

Schema.org is a schema; it's a mapping of identifiers, like http://schema.org/telephone, to semantics like [telephone number](http://schema.org/telephone).  It's a common vocabulary that allows domain agnostic components to do useful things.

These are commonly seen in hypermedia representations of messages, where they serve the dual purpose of describing data and telling you where to look up more information.